# Button name property not responding to .cs call

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, tags

Error is as follows:

> The name "b4" does not exist in the current context

XAML:

```
<Button x:Name="b1" Click="MainBclick()" Tag="1" Content="Setting Names"/>
<Button x:Name="b4" Content="Setting Usages" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
```

C#:

```
private void MainBclick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var y = ((Button)sender).Tag;
    int x = Convert.ToInt32(y);

    if (x == 1)
    {
        b4.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
    else { };
}
```

Basically if a certain button is pressed and its tag is equal to 1 then change the visibility of this other button.

The actual bit of code "b4" in XAML is giving me errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your designer file is properly generated.

Comment: There might be some syntax problem in xaml and it does not give you compile time error.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to copy paste code into a new project just in case. Unfortunately I get the problem on compile as well.

Answer (score 1):

Below Line is what causing you a Problem:

```
 <Button x:Name="b1" Click="MainBclick()" Tag="1" Content="Setting Names"/>
```

you cannot have "()" in your event handler method name

instead use:

```
<Button x:Name="b1" Click="MainBclick" Tag="1" Content="Setting Names"/>
```

Comment: Doing what you advised gave me more errors but when accompanied with a fresh designer file worked a treat. Thanks for the debug :D

Answer (score 1):

```
<Button x:Name="b1" Click="MainBclick" Tag="1" Content="Setting Names"/>
```

worked for me. Just remove the () from Click event.

Comment: Thanks very much. I was getting so many errors that a fresh designer file accompanied by the change you suggest made it work. ^^